# SQL DB2 Find and Display Common

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am working on a query in which I need to find all pair of distinct customers who bought atleast one title in common and display it, with the customer with higher id as the first customer A and customer B being the one with lower id. The schema looks like

```
create table customer (
 id   smallint  not null,
 name  varchar(20)
 primary key (id))

create table purchase (
 id    smallint     not null,
 title  varchar(25)  not null,
 primary key (id,title))
```

Here is the query I wrote but its not outputting the desired result

```
Select 
  distinct A.name as customera,B.name as customerb 
  from customer A,customer B, purchase C 
  where A.id=C.id and B.id=C.id
```

But this is yeilding a wrong result to what I want. I am a beginner in sql and this database is what i got to work on.

My output should look like this which It does but it displays both customers as same which is wrong.

```
   CUSTOMERA                          CUSTOMERB
 --------------------               --------------------
 Some customer with a higher id      other customer
```

Any help on this or how i can fix this.

Comment: What is the column which links a customer to an item purchased?  This is not clear to me.  Also, you are using old school pre ANSI-92 style joins in your query.  Consider using explicit join syntax instead.

Comment: This is all that is and there are a bunch of other tables in the database. the only table with the customer name is what I gave. And its the id that links the customer. like the customers use their id to purchase a title.

Answer (score 0):

First, *never* use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use proper, explicit, standard `join` syntax.

Assuming that the `id` in `purchase` matches the `id` in customer, then you can just do:

```
select distinct p1.id, p2.id
from purchase p1 join
     purchase p2
     on p2.title = p1.title and p1.id > p2.id;
```

Comment: But your query displays id's. I want it to display names of customers if titles are same.

Comment: and I will use join from next time sure.

Comment: @JSProgrammer . . . You should be able to add `join`'s into t his query.

Comment: you mean I need to add another join to display names?